# Pandas Dataframe - Append dataframes (Multiple columns/rows + Multiple columns, single row)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

More adventures in dataframes :)

So, I've pretty much have all the basics, however, this one is stumping me. I have two dataframes (pictures below). The first (techIndicator) has a ton of columns and rows, all filled properly. The second dataframe (social) has multiple columns, but only one row.

I need to add the columns (working as per the SS), but I want to duplicate the social dataframe's row all the way down to "fill in the nan's".

Here is the code that I'm using to concatenate all of the dataframes into a single one (all work except for social):

```
techIndicator = pd.concat([inter_day, macd, rsi, ema, vwap, adx, dmi, social], axis = 1)
techIndicator.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
techIndicator.dropna()
techIndicator.reset_index(drop=True)
```

As per the SS's below, the first threerows should look like:

```
datetime1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ......| 9 | 8| 7 | 6
datetime2 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 | ......| 9 | 8| 7 | 6
datetime3 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | ......| 9 | 8| 7 | 6
```

Instead, the concatenate above adds the columns, but deletes the values (I already checked the data types, they're all float64's)

Please help =)  My google-fu isn't working for this >.<

With help from Alex below, I was able to solve the many issues that I was having!

```
    dfTemp = pd.concat([inter_day, macd, rsi, ema, vwap, adx, dmi], axis = 1)
    dfTemp.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
    dfTemp.dropna()
    dfTemp.reset_index(inplace = True)
    

    long_social = social
    for a in range(dfTemp.shape[0] - 1):
        long_social=pd.concat([long_social, social])
    long_social.reset_index(inplace = True)
    long_social.drop(columns = ['index'], inplace = True)
    
    techIndicator = pd.concat([dfTemp, long_social], axis = 1)
    techIndicator.rename(columns={'date': 'Date',
                                  '1. open': 'Open',
                                  '2. high': 'High',
                                  '3. low': 'Low',
                                  '4. close': 'Close',
                                  '5. volume': 'Volume',
                                  'DX': 'DMI'}, inplace=True)

    techIndicator.dropna(inplace=True)
    techIndicator.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    techIndicator.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    techIndicator.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

[image: Main dataframe: techIndicator]

[image: Dataframe to append]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have a solution for you which does not use concat to add the columns to your main dataset, but it gets the job done.

The flow of it is since the two dataframes are not of even size, we make them even sized and the just loop through to add the columns by naming them.

```
# first create a copy of your social_df which we will append it to for as long as your main df is

long_soial=social_df

for a in range(main_df.shape[0]):
    social_long=pd.concat([social_long, social])

# now you have a long_social_df with the same length as your main df

social_vars=list(social.columns)  # Get the column names from social for naming them as we add to the main df

for i, var in enumerate(social_vars):
    main_df[var]=list[social_long[i] # add the columns by creating a new empty column with the desired name and adding the social info as a list to the named column
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I was able to adapt your code to populate the rows, and I also figured out some other bugs that was going on. I'll post the full working code.

Comment: Great! I'm glad to see you got it to run the way you wanted. Hope you get some cool stuff out of the data